# .htaccess -> Characters not escaping in rewrite string "(" ")"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to add some redirects from a very old site that had PDFs and some of these PDFs have used brackets to contain the years.

For example:

```
/document%2070C11-name%20(2012).pdf
```

So the full URL I am trying to redirect is:

```
https://website.co.uk/document/1/document%2070C11-name%20(2012).pdf
```

I have previously setup many different redirects on this site but ones with the special characters seem to be causing an issue.

Here is the examples of what I have tried, and failed with so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^document/1/document%2070C11-name%20\(2008\).pdf$ document/newurl/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^document/1/document%2070C11-name%20(.*)2008(.*).pdf$ document/newurl/ [R=301,L]
```

So I tried escaping the character and just trying a wildcard. Neither seemed to work on my Apache server. The code I used did seem to work when I tested it on:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

But I am pretty stuck now and would love any help I can get.

Thanks,
Kane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `%MN` character in URL, you need to use `\xMN` in the `RewriteRule` pattern.

Hence this rule should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^document/1/document\x2070C11-name\x20\(2008\)\.pdf$ /document/newurl/ [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

This will redirect `https://website.co.uk/document/1/document%2070C11-name%20(2008).pdf` to `https://website.co.uk/document/newurl/`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava. You're a hero.